# Can't Install any Linux Distro on new AMD Ryzen 7 5700U Mini PC

Tags: linux, boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Proxmox on a new machine (GMKteck NucBox M5 Pro Mini PC) but keep getting the following error :

> EFI boot mode detected, mounting efivars filesystem mount:
> /sys/firmware/efi/efivars: mount(2) system call failed: Operation not
> supported.
>
> dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
>
> Installation aborted - unable to continue (type exit or CTRL-D to reboot)

I've also tried installing Ubuntu and Arch Linux and they both fail with a very similar error.

The bios seems to have no option for legacy boot so it's booting in UEFI mode by default.

Any help would be appreciated.

[proxmox install screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdwIV.jpg)

Comment: Do you have other OS installed (e.g.Windows) or has the drive been used before? Hoe did you made the installation media?

Comment: No, just an empty NVME drive (it used to contain windows but all partitions have been wiped), trying to install from USB media, flashed with Etcher, Rufus and Ventoy (tried all, same result)

Comment: And you say you tried different ISOs? Are you sure they aren't corrupt?

Comment: No the ISO is fine, I've tried it on another machine without issue.

Comment: Let's try one thing (that shouldn't matter but maybe it does): Boot a live session (e.g. Ubuntu) instead of going directly to the installer, open GParted, select the target drive, then at the Device menu select Create new partition table..., choose "GPT". And perhaps it's a good idea to check other UEFI settings like drive mode and make sure it's AHCI. This is because "fake RAID" modes or Intel RST (not applicable here) aren't really supported yet in Linux.

Comment: I tried that using Ubuntu Desktop Live and did as you suggested with the drive, unfortunately still no luck.

Comment: If so you really need to check UEFI settings. Make sure CSM/Legacy is disabled, if applicable, drive mode AHCI, try disabling Secure Boot (again, shouldn't matter but maybe it does)... Of course, if there are UEFI and/or SSD firmware updates, do apply them.

Comment: I assume you talking about in the Bios? If so, it's very minimal, there's no UEFI settings, no mention of legacy or AHCI either. I have secure boot disabled but I've tried it enabled too.

Comment: if you have Secure Boot settings then you have UEFI, not BIOS. BIOS doesn't exist in the consumer/prosumer market since ~2012 and Windows 8. Some Users and some Vendors still call it, wrongly, "BIOS" or "UEFI BIOS" but that's besides the point. We're talking about the some thing, the firmware that initializes the PC and that you may need to update and/or update the firmware for the drive itself. It's a recurrent advice by the expert @oldfred in AskUbuntu and Unix&Linux. Other than that I have nothing else to suggest.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help

Comment: What mini PC? Mention the model int eh question; others might have the same issue *with that model*, and could provide help.

Comment: Thanks I've edit the original post, its a GMKteck NucBox M5 Mini PC

Comment: You can try loading the secure boot default certs inside the BIOS/UEFI . You should note though, that some of these systems use default certs which have either expired or will expire. Certainly the UM790 Pro from Minisforum which I purchased has certs which will expire in just over a year meaning that it becomes a brick if UEFI is enabled. And no, they have no interest in fixing it.

Comment: There's firmware update: https://www.gmktec.com/pages/firmware-update?spm=..product_d626229a-3228-4e6c-89d5-f5dbd4971953.header_1.1

Comment: That's the firmware that's installed on mine. I actually think the latest firmware is buggy. I noticed that the NucBox M5 Firmware files contain an 'EFI' folder and the M5 Pro (only difference is an extra NVMI slot) doesn't contain the 'EFI' folder, so I'm thinking the Bios firmware is missing some essential files.